# Find msg.sender(payer of the tx) in a solana program

Tags: transactions, program, payer

So i understand a msg.sender equivalent is the payer of the tx in solana , if so is there a way in vanilla solana or anchor to retrieve msg.sender i.e payer of the tx ?
as i understand it if there are 2 signers, they would be first 2 accounts in the accounts passed in that situation how do you determine who is the payer (vanilla solana)
also is there a way in anchor to do the same ? retrieve the payer of the tx ?

Comment: can you clarify whether you're trying to do this from the contract or client code?  it's not clear from the question or the engagement with the first answer

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity it is trivial to get this done via the client, was looking into how this could be done on chain in side the program, i believe the way to do it is trivial in barebones solana , not sure how to achieve this in anchor.

Answer (score 2):

**How to retrieve tx fee payer in raw tx**: it might not be the clearest source of info, but looking at the [Solana Explorer source code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/explorer/src/pages/TransactionDetailsPage.tsx#L411), you can see that indeed, it considers the first item in the `accountKeys` list as the fee payer, irrespective of the number of signers. So that's a (the?) way to find it in a raw transaction.

**Signers positioning**: [yes](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#account-addresses-format), signers are positioned first in the accounts array (some more info [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#signers)).

**Anchor-specific utility**: afaik Anchor does not have specific helpers to return the fee payer to you.

---

Note: If `msg.sender` is an Ethereum analogy I'd advise against leading with that, since it's... a Solana stack exchange :) That might not be any use to most people here to answer (I have no clue what it is)

---

**Edit**: [this bit](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/src/transaction.ts#L430) of web3.js highlights more clearly how signers are packed first, with the fee payer brought to the front.

---

**Edit 2**: This answer is geared towards accessing the fee payer client-side, **not** program-side. Short answer for program-side is: **no**, c.f. @trent.sol answer.

Comment: so technically it is safe to assume that the first account in my account slice is a signer and is the payer ? sad anchor does not expose the original accountinfo slice.

Comment: The fee payer is always the first account. You can see where this happens in @solana/web3.js: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f4100f621fbda534ba7e25c268b2875a36de03d4/web3.js/src/transaction.ts#L430 But as the answer/you say I don't think Anchor exposes it in that way

Comment: Yes. I made an edit to the answer with a better code reference.

Comment: ^ Edit made, see @trent.sol answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible today. While the things @man0s cites are true, the transaction's full accounts vector is not available to instructions.  Runtime only hands the instruction processor the subset of accounts that the instruction actually requests.  There's no way to directly request the fee-payer though.  The fee-payer could potentially be exposed via sysvar, but it's not clear to me what gotchas may exist.  This conversation should probably continue as a feature request issue on github, assuming one doesn't already exist

Comment: does it mean the way man0s described on how to retrieve the payer in vanilla solana programs is also not possible ? is it in the case that payer is not passed to the instruction but just used to pay for the tx in that case the accountinfo slice passed to entry point will not have the payer as the first account ?

Comment: correct. as the answer states, the accounts vector passed to an instruction processor is a subset of the full tx's accounts vector. that is, it is two levels of indirection. the instruction account vector as encoded in the transaction is an array of indexes into the transaction accounts vector. the transaction construction tooling doesn't have a direct way to reference transaction accounts by index, rather everything is specified by address and the mapping generated automatically behind the scenes.  theoretically, someone could handroll transaction construction to inject an index 0 reference